# How to use 以 ... 為主grammar?

Tags: translation, grammar, conversation

I am a little bit confused about how to use  `以 ... 為主` correctly in a sentence. Originally, I thought that it means "to put the main importance on ... ", but some people said that it has more tendency to mean "mostly". Can someone give an explanation about how this grammar is often used, or perhaps, the correct way to use this grammar? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, as they are essentially equal

Your thinking "...the **main** importance on..." implies there is more than one important thing but this one carries the most weight or **mostly** carried by it.

Comment: Ah, I see. But for example, if I want to say "Right now I am prioritizing the development of this field", I can say "我目前以此領域的發展為主", right? Because for some people , it's more towards "我目前比較看重此領域的發展". What do you think about this? Do you think that these two are essentially the same?

Comment: They are somewhat different. Your sentence sounds more definite and determined on the subject - the development of this region has the highest priority. The other sentence indicates the importance of the subject is only slightly above others - among things to do, I am focusing more on the development of this region.

Answer (score 0):

You may translate it by "as ... being the most important", or "taking ... as the most important"